# How do I style a toggle switch with useStyles instead of withStyles in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an input form switch in Material UI and I'd like the track and button to be red when on, exactly like in [this example](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#sizes). All the [switch styling examples](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#customized-switches) on Material UI's website use withStyles, but I'm unsure why I can't use useStyles instead? Is it possible to do it with useStyles?

Here is my attempt which is not working!

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  switchBase: {
    '&$checked + $track': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  },
}));

export default function SwitchesSize() {
const classes = useStyles()
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleChecked = () => {
    setChecked((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch size="small" checked={checked} onChange={toggleChecked} />}
        label="Small"
        classes={{ switchBase: classes.switchBase }}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Katie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style the `Switch` with `useStyles` root component needs to be targeted.

```
<FormGroup>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Switch
        color="default"
        classes={{
          track: classes.switchTrack,
          switchBase: classes.switchBase,
        }}
        size="small"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={toggleChecked}
      />
    }
    label="Small"
    // classes={{ switchBase: classes.switchBase }}
  />
</FormGroup>
```

useStyles object:-

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    switchTrack: {
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    },
    switchBase: {
        color: "#000",
        "&.Mui-checked": {
            color: "green"
        },
        "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }
    },
}));
```

working sandbox link:- https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-wave-e9otk

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but this doesn't seem to work for me? I edited your sandbox to check and if you change the backgroundColor from red to blue, it stays red, so I think it must be red on yours by default. Mine defaults to grey because of my theme and I want to override it. Do you know how to make yours blue? Many thanks

Comment: Hey, I've updated the answer. Sorry for the last time not cross-checking the answer. I thought that only the line `const classes = useStyles()` is missing. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much Rajiv - I never would have realised that the class applies to the switch within the control. Thanks again for saving me a lot of time! :)

Comment: hey, can you do this exact thing with a button? change the color of a button based on the state? i am having some difficulties doing that.

Comment: hey, what you've tried till now and which version of MUI you're using?